# Adding values in a new column based on column name of other dataset

Tags: r

Currently I have two datasets. One with locations within the company and the amount of products that are being produced at each location on each day. The other with the locations and the capacity of each location on each day. I have illustrated both of them below.

Dataset 1 (Amount of products product on certain days of the week):

| Location | Day of the week | Produced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location A | Monday | 20 |
| Location B | Monday | 30 |
| Location C | Monday | 55 |
| Location A | Tuesday | 25 |
| Location B | Tuesday | 24 |
| Location C | Tuesday | 70 |

Dataset 2 (The capacity of each location on each day of the week)

| Location | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location A | 50 | 50 |
| Location B | 60 | 50 |
| Location C | 80 | 80 |

What I want to do is add a new column to the first dataset. I want that column to be named 'Capacity' and I want it to kinda look like this:

| Location | Day of the week | Produced | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location A | Monday | 20 | 50 |
| Location A | Tuesday | 25 | 50 |

I've tried multiple ifelse statements, but failed miserably and are working on it for quite some time now. Is there someone who might know a fix?

Answer (score 2):

You can `pivot_longer` *df2* and then `merge` *df1* and *df2*

```
library(tidyr)

merge(df1, 
      pivot_longer(df2, colnames(df2[,2:3]), 
                   names_to="Day of the week", values_to="Capacity"),
      by=c("Location","Day of the week"))
    Location Day of the week Produced Capacity
1 Location A          Monday       20       50
2 Location A         Tuesday       25       50
3 Location B          Monday       30       60
4 Location B         Tuesday       24       50
5 Location C          Monday       55       80
6 Location C         Tuesday       70       80
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c("Location A", "Location B", "Location C", 
"Location A", "Location B", "Location C"), `Day of the week` = c("Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday"), Produced = c(20L, 
30L, 55L, 25L, 24L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(Location = c("Location A", "Location B", "Location C"
), Monday = c(50L, 60L, 80L), Tuesday = c(50L, 50L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your Capacity data into long format and then merge. Here I use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` for the former and then `dplyr::left_join()` for the latter.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- structure(list(Location = c("Location A", "Location B", "Location C", "Location A", "Location B", "Location C"), Day_of_week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday"), Produced = c(20L, 30L, 55L, 25L, 24L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

d2 <- structure(list(Location = c("Location A", "Location B", "Location C"), Monday = c(50L, 60L, 80L), Tuesday = c(50L, 50L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

d2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Location, names_to = "Day_of_week", values_to = "Capacity") %>% 
  left_join(d1, .)
#> Joining, by = c("Location", "Day_of_week")
#>     Location Day_of_week Produced Capacity
#> 1 Location A      Monday       20       50
#> 2 Location B      Monday       30       60
#> 3 Location C      Monday       55       80
#> 4 Location A     Tuesday       25       50
#> 5 Location B     Tuesday       24       50
#> 6 Location C     Tuesday       70       80
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>